# Getting different results from function. How to retrieve values correctly?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

Trying to implement PI controller in function.
Already worked for one controller. 
However, for more than one controller, the results are shifting.
Suppose to get same values in the following code.
Any help I appreciate it.

```
float r_in_1 = 10.00;
float y_out_1 = 5.00;

float r_in_2 = 10.00;
float y_out_2 = 5.00;

float r_o_1;
float y_o_1;

float r_o_2;
float y_o_2;

float vi_1 = 0;
float vi_2 = 0;

void setup() {

 Serial.begin(9600);

  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

r_o_1 = pow_2(r_in_1);

r_o_2 = pow_2(r_in_2);

y_o_1 = pow_2(y_out_1);

y_o_2 = pow_2(y_out_2);


vi_1 = PI_1(r_o_1, y_o_1);
vi_2 = PI_1(r_o_2, y_o_2);

Serial.print(vi_1);
Serial.print(',');
Serial.println(vi_2);
delay(1000);

}


float pow_2(float x){

float z;

z = x*x;

return z;

}

float PI_1(float r, float y){

float e;
static float sum_e=0;
float vi;
float kp=2.00;
float ki=10.00;

e = r - y;
sum_e =  sum_e + e;
vi = kp * e + ki * sum_e;

return vi;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'more than one controller'? Please be detailed about what you are trying to achieve, and what is wrong the current result

Comment: The current result should become same value for vi_1 and vi_2. But it is shifting.

Comment: I mean when I comment out one of those  vi_1 = PI_1(r_o_1, y_o_1); or
vi_2 = PI_1(r_o_2, y_o_2); it is working fine. But when both of them are executing the result are shifting.

Comment: what is your current result? I am a bit confused by "shifting". Edit your question, add the result you got.

Comment: Ok, what I suppose to get is this  (vi_1,vi_2) is what I get in serial monitor. (900,900), (1650,1650), (2400,2400) ,(3150,3150), (3900,3900)

Comment: However, I am getting these (900,1650), (2400,3150), (3900,4650)

Comment: You see that  values are shifting, but they actually should  be identical.

Comment: Zalt, please *edit the question* to include that additional information, instead of just putting it in throwaway comments.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you declare `static float sum_e` in PI_1 function. The value of will increase everytime PI_1 function is called. In 1 loop, you call PI_1 two times, resulting first call always smaller than second call because of the value of `sum_e`. Sum of error should be declared as global variable, and each controller has its own "sum" variable.
**Declare as global :**

```
float sum_e[100]; //for 100 controller.
```

**Your function**

```
float PI_1(float r, float y,int number){

float e;
float vi;
float kp=2.00;
float ki=10.00;

e = r - y;
sum_e[number] =  sum_e[number] + e;    //integrator for controller number
vi = kp * e + ki * sum_e[number];

return vi;
    }
```

**function call**

```
vi_1 = PI_1(r_o_1, y_o_1,1);
vi_2 = PI_1(r_o_2, y_o_2,2);
```

Here is the rough example. There are lot more efficient ways than this, but this should gives you some idea. You can reduce the code yourself since the values should be correct already.

Comment: If I remove static then the integrator term will not work. I mean it just prints same values constantly.

Comment: I edit my answer

Comment: what I want to do is to reduce the code.

Comment: I would like to have only one PI function. As the matter of fact  i have more controllers.

Comment: use array. you can also use it for other variables like r_o y_o vi_ etc.

Answer (score 1):

A PI controller has “state”: it has to remember the sum of all the
previous errors. If you want several controllers you have to
independently store the state of each one.

The traditional solution used by C programmers is to write a controller
function that takes an extra parameter which is a pointer to the state.
In C++ you can use a reference instead:

```c++
// PI controller.
float PIController(float &sum, float r, float y)
{
    const float kp = 2.00;
    const float ki = 10.00;

    float e = r - y;  // error
    sum += e;         // integral of error
    return kp * e + ki * sum;
}
```

You would use it like this:

```c++
void loop()
{
    static float sum_1, sum_2;  // State of the controllers.
    // ...
    vi_1 = PIController(sum_1, r_o_1, y_o_1);
    vi_2 = PIController(sum_2, r_o_1, y_o_1);
}
```

The C++ language provides a nicer way of writing the same thing: you can
use a class to wrap the state and the controlling method together under
the same name:

```c++
// PI controller.
class PIController {
public:
    PIController() : sum(0) {}
    float operator()(float r, float y);
private:
    float sum;
};

float PIController::operator()(float r, float y)
{
    const float kp = 2.00;
    const float ki = 10.00;

    float e = r - y;  // error
    sum += e;         // integral of error
    return kp * e + ki * sum;
}
```

Which you would use like this:

```c++
void loop()
{
    static PIController pi_1, pi_2;  // Controller instances.
    // ...
    vi_1 = pi_1(r_o_1, y_o_1);
    vi_2 = pi_2(r_o_1, y_o_1);
}
```

The generated assembly should not be much different. Note that in both
cases the static variables of `loop()` could be globals if you prefer.